# Alternative capture group numbering in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

(?| .. )

The above syntax is available in Perl. I have tried the same in JavaScript it is not working for me.

Could anyone suggest me how can we using it from JavaScript?

I'm trying to convert the following regex to use in JavaScript:

```
(?|\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?))
```

Comment: it's called branch reset feature. Js won't support this.

Comment: Is there any alternative option available?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dZ8wJ3/1 

The same should be done in JavaScript that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all regex with branch reset has an equivalent version without. However, the regex in your case can be trivially rewritten to avoid the use to branch reset feature.

Let us look at your regex:

```
(?|
  \s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|
  \s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|
  \s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)
)
```

Since the next alternative is essentially prefix of the previous alternative down to the syntax, you can merge the two branches by making the tail part optional.

Let us look at a simplified view of your regex:

```
(?|
  ABC|
  AB|
  C
)
```

The regex can be rewritten without branch reset:

```
A(?:B(?:C)?)?
```

The rewritten regex doesn't sacrifice any functionality in the original regex. You can even use this regex to replace the regex you currently use in PCRE.

```
\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)(?:[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)(?:[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?))?)?
```

Comment: Very good approach at problem solving. Simplify the situation to extract a pattern, find a solution and then apply it to the original problem. You deserve your rep!

Answer (score 2):

Just turn `(?|...)` [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to `(?:..)` a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
(?:\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?)|\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ms[\.]com)?))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dZ8wJ3/2)

And get the strings you want from group index 7,8,9,10. With branch reset, you would get the matches from index 1,2,3,4.

Comment: I want to get the branch matches only 1,2,3,4 for some reasons. That's why I used this (?|...).